# Central divisible subgroup

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

Have you any nice example of central divisible subgroup of a finitely presented group ? (of course the subgroup has not to be trivial)

Comment: This depends on what you understand by a "nice example". Have you read the discussion on MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23352/ ?

Comment: I read this discussion and I hoped it was simpler for another divisible group than Q. A nice example would be a well-known group or a presentation with few generators and relators.

Answer (score 0):

I found a weak solution of my problem: Let $A_n$ denote the Abel group. For $n \geq 4$, $A_n$ is finitely presented and $Z(A_n) \simeq Z[1/p]$ is $p$-divisible.